# JQuery AJAX FormData from Chrome won't parse in .Net WebMethod

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, webmethod

I have a bunch of jquery-based ajax calls that I am handling on a VB.Net back-end for a client.  Everything is working fine in IE, but I can't get it to work on any other client.  Below is a sample of the ajax call.  I don't think there's actually a problem on the client side.

```
            function gallery_update() {
                var product_id = document.getElementById("hid_product_id").value;
                var requestdata = new FormData();
                requestdata.append("product_id", product_id);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Admin/Product/WebService.asmx/Gallery_Update",
                    async: true,
                    data: requestdata,
                    contentType: "multipart/form-data;charset=ISO-8859-1",
                    processData: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (responsedata) {
                        gallery_draw(responsedata.childNodes['0'].textContent);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
```

On the server side I have a web service that starts off like this:

```
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
<System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function Gallery_Update() As String
        Dim output As String = ""
        Dim Product_ID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("product_id")
        Dim one_product As prod_Product = New prod_Product()
        one_product.Read(Product_ID)
        Dim all_images As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
```

So, everything works as expected in IE, but in chrome (and firefox), the request.form collection is always empty.

I've done some streamreader code to troubleshoot it, and I see that the request body looks like this:

```
"------WebKitFormBoundaryYbtyKCr4yuYdjtMm  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="product_id"    1  ------WebKitFormBoundaryYbtyKCr4yuYdjtMm--  "
"-----------------------------7e239e1fd0936  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="product_id"    2  -----------------------------7e239e1fd0936--  "
```

(top from chrome, bottom from ie) and I don't really see any problem there. cr and lf are rendered as whitespace, but they are what I'd expect.

My only real guess is that there's some problem with the webkit boundaries.  Looks like IE uses hex for its boundaries and chrome is using a more general string format.

Comment: Some additional comments.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013, on a Windows 10 laptop.  I have several other versions of Visual Studio installed.  My client has a Windows 2008 server (and gets the same behavioral problems).

Comment: I think the root of the issue is that a boundary is not being provided in the content-type header of the request for some reason.  A lot of internet research doesn't appear to reveal this happening to other people, so that seems weird.  I've tinkered with my ajax quite a bit to force it null, undefined, remove it, etc... with no content-type, it seems to go with application/x-www-form-urlencoded but there's still boundaries in the body.